# Folder as a source for WIX Installer

Tags: c#, wix

How to tell WIX installer to use whole folder as a srouce not single file.
This is my sample **Product.wxs**. When I install it it only copy one "exe" file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="installer" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="google" UpgradeCode="b9a36165-554f-493b-8e11-f2aef7fb90a3">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="installer" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="myProduct" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component>
        <File Id="MyFiles" Name="$(var.MyProduct.UI.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.MyProduct.UI.TargetDir)" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware you have to have all the files in your wix project if you want to include them into your installer.

To get all the files you can use the [Harvest Tool (Heat)](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html)

Comment: Heat is the right approach. It can be run as a VS build event.